# Visual Studio Code is not successfully installing extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to install extensions is Visual Studio Code. I am experiencing the same behavior with several different extensions.

I've tried two ways:

1. `ctrl + shift + P`, then `Extensions: Install Extensions`. I select my extension of choice and press `install`. The icon dims and says `installing`, but does not ever change. The extension does not appear to have installed.
2. In the integrated terminal I run `code --install-extension <extension name>`. I get the feedback `Found <extension name> in the marketplace. Installing...` Almost immediately, the command is executed yet no extension was installed.

I am running VSCode version 1.12.2 as an administrator. My machine is running Windows 10 enterprise.

Is anyone here familiar with this issue? Thanks.

Edit: The issue persists in version 1.15.1, but now gives and error after running `code --install-extension <extension name>`. The error reads:

```
(node:7412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejections     
(rejection id:1): TypeError: this._state.then is not a function.
(node:7412) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: VS Code is currently at v1.15.1. Is there a reason you are intentionally remaining at v1.12.2?

Comment: Good question--no. I updated to 1.1.15.1 and restarted. Unfortunately, the issue is persisting and I am seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server at work? If so, you can try setting the `http.proxy` configuration to the proxy server address. Beyond that, make sure you are giving the installer enough time to complete.